# Importing modules from different folder python for unknown path

Tags: python

I have been working on a python project and I am new to it.
I have made a small library for my project in which I have several different modules doing different tasks.

For example: I have 5 modules namely add, subtract, multiply, divide and root.
I call all these `.pyc` files into my `main.py` file and my code runs properly **if all of them are in the same folder**.

Now, I want to store my `main.py` at: `D:\project\main.py`
and these 5 `.pyc` files at : `D:\project\Lib\` (In the Lib folder)

I found a solution as to mention the path of the folder Lib into the code but I can not do so as I need to submit the code somewhere and if they try to run this on their PC, it might not import these files.

What would be the possible solution to this?

Comment: see about python packages. you need to convert a directory into a package by creating a file `__init__.py` in it. and then store all your modules and call it like `from package.module import something`

Comment: @anekix I found it thank you so much! :)

Comment: refer my answer below

Comment: also make sure you work with  `.py` files instead of `.pyc` files. `.pyc` files will be generated by interprer for its internal purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `D:\project\Lib` create an `__init__.py` file. and put all your modules in `D:\project\Lib` now `lib` works as a python package.you dir structure should now look like this:

```
D:\project\Lib
           |
           +--- __init__.py
           +--- add.py
           +--- sub.py
           +--- multiply.py
```

Now from any file inside (say for ex main.py)  `D:\project` call any module you want like this.

`from Lib.add import something`.

final dir structure will roughly look like this.

```
D:\project
        |
        +-- main.py
        +-- Lib
              |
              +--- __init__.py
              +--- add.py
              +--- sub.py
              +--- multiply.py
```

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a package.

Use a directory structure like this:

```
.
+-- main.py
+-- lib
    +-- __init__.py
    +-- add.pyc
    +-- substract.pyc
    +-- ...
```

Then, in your `main.py` file, you can import them like this:

```
from lib import add
```

[More on packages on Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Comment: @BrightOne. its not good idea to use `.pyc` fils directly rather they are generated by the python interpreter

Comment: @anekix OP used `.pyc` in the examples, it's not my own decision. Nonetheless, you are right.